# Normal vector of a cone pointing outward

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Consider a cone with height $h$ and maximum radius $R$.

Assume that the vertex of the cone is in $(0,0,0)$ and its axis is the $z$-axis.

For $(x,y,z)$ lying in the outside of the cone I want to determine the normal vector pointing away from the cone.

My plan is to use adjusted cylindrical coordinates:

$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}z\frac{R}{h}\cos(\phi)\\z\frac{R}{h}\sin(\phi)\\z\end{pmatrix}=:\psi(\phi, z)$

and then calculating $\frac{\psi_\phi\times\psi_z}{\|\psi_\phi\times\psi_z\|_2}$ where $\times$ is the cross product:

$\psi_\phi\times\psi_z=(-z\frac{R}{h}\sin(\phi),z\frac{R}{h}\cos(\phi),0)\times(\frac{R}{h}\cos(\phi),\frac{R}{h}\sin(\phi),1)$.

And then using $x\times y:=\begin{pmatrix}x_2y_3-x_3y_2\\x_3y_1-x_1y_3\\x_1y_2-x_2y_1\end{pmatrix}$

Does this work this way?

Comment: What are $\psi_r$ and $\psi_\phi$? And why did you write $\psi(r,\phi)$ instead of $\psi(r,\phi,z)$?

Comment: And how do you take the cross product of $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}$ with anything?

Comment: I made some mistakes with indices. $R$ and $h$ are fixed, so we only have $\psi$ as a function of $\phi$ and $z$. See my edit above

Comment: I think that cross product works. It was the naming of the vectors $\psi_\phi$ and $\psi_z$ that was confusing to me. It looks like you mean $\psi_\phi$ to be the cylindrical basis vector at $\psi(\phi,z),$ but what you call $\psi_z$ is $\frac1z\psi(\phi,z).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cylindrical coordinates are hopefuly not the most appropriate in this case.

It looks to me simpler to work with cartesian coordinates.

For this, we need the cartesian equation of this cone, which is :

$$f(x,y,z) := x^2+y^2-(Rz/h)^2=0$$

(why that ? If such a cone is cut by plane $z=z_0$, its horizontal "slices" are circles centered in $(0,0)$ with equation $x^2+y^2=(Rz/h)^2$ ; in particular, when $z_0=0$ we get a radius equal to $0$ ;  when $z_0=h$ we get a radius equal to $R$).

Therefore, the outward normal vector is

> $$(\partial f/\partial x, \ \partial f/\partial y, \ \partial f/\partial z)=\left(2x, \ 2y, \ \frac{2R^2z}{h^2}\right)$$

Comment: The vertex of the cone, not the center of its base circle, was supposed to be at $(0,0,0).$ I believe the cylindrical coordinates in the question are correct. If you make that adjustment, I think this answer works out.

Comment: @David K Thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, doing my method I arrive at $(\frac{zR\cos(\phi)}{h},\frac{zR\sin(\phi)}{h},\frac{-R^2z}{h^2})$. Transforming back equals the "same" result as yours except for the length and that my $z$ coordinate is negative but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If it is negative, it means it is the inward normal. It suffices to invert the component vectors of the cross product.